# Orchard : Widgets positions in a same Zone

Tags: widget, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8, orchard-modules

There is a Zone named: AfterContent , which contains three Projection Widgets for getting the resource items ( resource items is a custom Content type created )
[image]

I was expecting that the order in which these 3 widgets will display on the Page will be: Third Party, Free Distributable, Copyright, because that's exactly the order of Widgets in the Zone as seen in above image.

But the surprising part was that the "Free Distributable Resources" appears first, "Third Party Resources" widget 2nd and "Copyright Resources" widget at 3rd.

PLease help me understand why the Widget at Position 2 in Zone appears at position 1 in Page ? is Orchard using some random calculation to determine the positions of widgets in a same Zone ?

Comment: It should be the way you described... Check that you chose the right projections inside.

Comment: Yes, I checked again. The projections/Query are correct inside e.g Third Part Projection querying Third Party resource items only. Same for others.

Comment: That's strange. Check each query with previewing it. Otherwise, it should work.

Comment: Edit each widget and look at the exact order number they have.

Comment: Ok. So suspect that issue somewhere is in querying only or the oder field in Widgets ?. Let me check again evry thing...